# Image request with different headers

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Img field on the page that is loaded from an external source:

```
<img src="wwww.external-source.com"/>
```

The image will be loadded is according to the user-agent.
Is there a way to hook the request while loading the image so that the headers can be changed?
If this is not possible, is it possible to cancel the loading process,and send another request instead?

Thanks

Comment: If the site has CORS you can use fetch, though CORS is rare for image hosts. Even with fetch you cannot set certain headers like user-agent

Comment: No CROS verification in this case

Comment: If you use fetch you have to use CORS

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use different headers for image, I would suggest you to use `fetch` api to download the image with customer headers like:

```
fetch("https://i.picsum.photos/id/525/200/300.jpg?hmac=Dhg6JV7Cl1oDtYMG0pq3hVUbGQjEpOX41178aR7_eh8", {
  headers: {
    "Some": "header",
  }
})
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blobData => {
    console.log(blobData)
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      const base64data = reader.result;
      // this is the data you can use in src attribute of img
      console.log(base64data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: The problem with this technique is that the image will load twice.
First time for "img src =" ', and second time for this JS.
Is there a way to cancel the first loading without changing the tag?

Comment: Not if you inset the `img` tag dynamically after fetching the image blob, and meanwhile we can have a placeholder div